# Obtener la cantidad de páginas y palabras de cada archivo de Word en Filestack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy usando Filestack v3, de acuerdo a su documentación [Document Transformation](https://www.filestack.com/docs/document-transformations) necesito obtener la información de cada archivo de Word (DOC/DOCX) al subirlo a Filestack, estos valores se ponen en unos hidden inputs creados dentro de un div con id "**result**", dichos valores los obtengo vía JSON. Tengo esto:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="files">UPLOAD</button>
<textarea id="dkd"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.filestackapi.com/v3/filestack.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi código JS es:

```
$("#files").click(function(){
var client = filestack.init('myAPI');

client.pick({
accept: ['image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif','application/pdf','application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'],
fromSources: ['local_file_system','googledrive','gmail','facebook','dropbox','onedrive','webcam'],
lang: 'es',     
maxSize: 2097152,
maxFiles: 100
}).then(function(Blobs) {

 var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
 for(var i=0; i<result.filesUploaded.length; i++){
     switch(result.filesUploaded[i].mimetype)
     {
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/png":
        case "image/gif":
        case "application/pdf": 
              //do some actions
        break;

        case "application/msword":
        case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":

         var lcconvert = "https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/"+result.filesUploaded[i].handle;
         var dataFilee = "https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/output=docinfo:true/"+result.filesUploaded[i].handle;

            $("#dkd").load(lcconvert, function(){ //load doc/docx files text in a textarea

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "fileword.php",
                data:{
                   url: $("#dkd").val(),
                   dF: dataFilee
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                   var numw = $.trim(data.numberwords);
                   var numpagp = $.trim(data.numberpages);          

                   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='wordsnumber[]' value='"+numw+"'><input type='hidden' name='pagesnumber[]' value='"+numpagp+"'><input type='hidden' name='url[]' value='"+dataFilee+"'>";
               },
              complete: function(data)
              {                        
                 $(".overlay").hide();                  
              }
            });//ajax
            });//dkd load
     }//switch
 }//for
}); // client.pick
}); //#files click
```

Cuando cargo un sólo archivo funciona genial pero cuando subo más de un archivo Word sigue mostrando la información del primer archivo y no la información que le corresponde como aparece en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo arreglarlo? Necesito su ayuda.

Comment: puedes mostrar el json de la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

si quieres que el archivo no se acumule solo cambia esto:

`document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='wordsnumber[]' value='"+numw+"'><input type='hidden' name='pagesnumber[]' value='"+numpagp+"'><input type='hidden' name='url[]' value='"+dataFilee+"'>";`

por esto:

`document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' name='wordsnumber[]' value='"+numw+"'><input type='hidden' name='pagesnumber[]' value='"+numpagp+"'><input type='hidden' name='url[]' value='"+dataFilee+"'>";`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no es lo que busco, quiero que cada archivo que se sube se creen 3 inputs hidden con su respectivo valor, como se muestra en la imagen los campos del segundo archivo se están repitiendo con los valores del primero, el segundo archivo tiene una cantidad diferente de páginas y su link es distinto.

Comment: @NekoLopez puedes mostrar el json de la respuesta